# play json, recursive reads, npe

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, play-json

I have two case classes:

First:

```
object Person {
  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[Person]
}

case class Person(name: String, coWorkers: List[CoWorker])
```

Person may have 0 or some CoWorkers

Second:

```
object CoWorker {
  implicit val jsonFormat: Format[CoWorker] = Json.format[CoWorker]
}

case class CoWorker(position: String, person: Person)
```

I made test:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import play.api.libs.json.{JsError, JsArray, Json}

class NestedSpec extends Specification {

  "Nested" should {

    "jsonReads" in {

      val personJson = Json.obj(
        "name" -> "alex",
        "coWorkers" -> Json.arr(
          Json.obj(
            "person" -> Json.obj(
              "name" -> "jack",
              "coWorkers" -> List.empty[String]
            ),
            "position": "developer" 
          )
        )
      )

      val res = personJson.validate[Person].asEither

      res.left.map(err => println(Json.prettyPrint(JsError.toJson(err))))

      res.isRight must beTrue

    }

  }

}
```

But that test fails with errors:

```
> testOnly  nested.NestedSpec
[info] NestedSpec
[info] 
[info] Nested should
[error]   ! jsonReads
[error]    java.lang.NullPointerException: null (JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:99)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1.apply(JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1.apply(JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8.reads(Reads.scala:126)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$2.reads(Format.scala:46)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$3$$anon$4.reads(Reads.scala:104)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$2.reads(Format.scala:46)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$5$$anonfun$inmap$1.apply(Format.scala:31)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$5$$anonfun$inmap$1.apply(Format.scala:31)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$1.reads(Format.scala:39)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Json$.fromJson(Json.scala:125)
[error] play.api.libs.json.LowPriorityDefaultReads$$anon$2$$anonfun$reads$1.apply(Reads.scala:168)
[error] play.api.libs.json.LowPriorityDefaultReads$$anon$2$$anonfun$reads$1.apply(Reads.scala:167)
[error] play.api.libs.json.LowPriorityDefaultReads$$anon$2.reads(Reads.scala:167)
[error] play.api.libs.json.DefaultFormat$$anon$4.reads(Format.scala:82)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:99)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1.apply(JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1.apply(JsConstraints.scala:32)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8.reads(Reads.scala:126)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$2.reads(Format.scala:46)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$3$$anon$4.reads(Reads.scala:104)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$2.reads(Format.scala:46)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$5$$anonfun$inmap$1.apply(Format.scala:31)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$5$$anonfun$inmap$1.apply(Format.scala:31)
[error] play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$1.reads(Format.scala:39)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.validate(JsValue.scala:18)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsObject.validate(JsValue.scala:76)
[error] nested.NestedSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(NestedSpec.scala:24)
[error] nested.NestedSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(NestedSpec.scala:10)
[info] 
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for specification NestedSpec
[info] Finished in 269 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 1 error
[info] 
[error] Error: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 1, Passed 0
[error] Error during tests:
[error]         nested.NestedSpec
[error] (test:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed May 18, 2016 12:25:16 PM
```

I suppose that it's kind of curricular dependency error. CoWorker uses Person's jsonReads and Person uses CoWorker jsonReads. Is it possible to solve this issue and get test running?

Answer (score 4):

I need to use lazyReads, found in docs:

> Recursive Types One special case that our example model doesn’t
>   demonstrate is how to handle Reads and Writes for recursive types.
>   JsPath provides lazyRead and lazyWrite methods that take call-by-name
>   parameters to handle this:
>
> ```
> case class User(name: String, friends: Seq[User])
>
> implicit lazy val userReads: Reads[User] = (
>   (__ \ "name").read[String] and
>   (__ \ "friends").lazyRead(Reads.seq[User](userReads))
> )(User)
>
> implicit lazy val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
>   (__ \ "name").write[String] and
>   (__ \ "friends").lazyWrite(Writes.seq[User](userWrites))
> )(unlift(User.unapply))
> ```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#recursive-types